# @ContextConfiguration is not inherited with Springockito

Tags: java, spring, spring-test, springockito

I am currently playing around with `springockito-annotations` and this requires `@RunWith` and `@ContextConfiguration` annotations in order to work. I would like to put these annotations on a superclass of my tests, but can't seem to get it to work.

Superclass:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class})
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringockitoContextLoader.class, locations = "classpath:spring/test-context.xml")
public class MyTestSuperclass {
    //...
```

Example testclass:

```
public class MyTest extends MyTestSuperclass {
    @Inject
    @ReplaceWithMock
    private MyService myService;
    //...
```

With this code, `myService` is not replaced with a mock.

But, if I change it to...

```
@ContextConfiguration
public class MyTest extends MyTestSuperclass {
    //...
```

...it works.

Is there a way to avoid having to add `@ContextConfiguration` to all my test classes? Has this perhaps been fixed in a newer version of `Spring`/`Spring-tests`? From what I can tell it is able to inherit the `locations` part from the superclass without annotating the subclass, but the `loader` part does not work without an annotation in the subclass. I'm using version 3.2.1.RELEASE of `Spring-test`.

Here is a sample projec that shows the bug:

http://www.filedropper.com/springockitobug

Comment: `spring-test` has supported inheritance of loaders since Spring Framework 3.0. So you should definitely not need to redeclare an empty `@ContextConfiguration`. There may be an issue with the Springockito implementation. Would you be willing to publish a minimal example project to demonstrate this behavior (e.g., on GitHub)?

Comment: I think the culprit is `springockito-annotations`, I also had issues when the annotated class had an un-annotated superclass, in these cases `@ReplaceWithMock` didn't work as well..

Comment: Added a minimal project. Couldn't reproduce the error in the above comment in the minimal project so must have been due to something else..

Comment: What do you mean you couldn't reproduce the error? I downloaded your sample project, and it definitely reproduced the original error. Your sample project is what I used to verify that `PatchedSpringockitoContextLoader` works. So... thanks for providing the sample project!

Comment: Was referring to the comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a [bug in Springockito](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/issues/35/mocks-stop-working-if-contextconfiguration).

`@ContextConfiguration` is in fact inherited, which has been true since it was introduced in Spring 2.5. Furthermore, the configured `loader` (i.e.,  `SpringockitoContextLoader` in this case) is also inherited, which has been true since Spring 3.0.

The issue here is that `SpringockitoContextLoader` incorrectly processes the *declaring class* (i.e., the class that is annotated with `@ContextConfiguration`) instead of the actual *test class* (which can be a subclass that inherits the declaration of `@ContextConfiguration`).

After thorough debugging, it turns out that the solution is quite simple (in fact simpler than the original `SpringockitoContextLoader` implementation).

The following `PatchedSpringockitoContextLoader` should work fine as a drop-in replacement for the broken `SpringockitoContextLoader`.

```java
import org.kubek2k.springockito.annotations.internal.Loader;

import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.MergedContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.GenericXmlContextLoader;

public class PatchedSpringockitoContextLoader extends GenericXmlContextLoader {

    private final Loader loader = new Loader();

    @Override
    protected void prepareContext(ConfigurableApplicationContext context, MergedContextConfiguration mergedConfig) {
        super.prepareContext(context, mergedConfig);
        this.loader.defineMocksAndSpies(mergedConfig.getTestClass());
    }

    @Override
    protected void customizeContext(GenericApplicationContext context) {
        super.customizeContext(context);
        this.loader.registerMocksAndSpies(context);
    }

}
```

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a super class, use an annotation.

For instance:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class})
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringockitoContextLoader.class, locations = "classpath:spring/test-context.xml")
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TestConfiguration {
}
```

Then, annotate your test classes with

```
@TestConfiguration 
public class MyTest  {
    @Inject
    @ReplaceWithMock
    private MyService myService;
    //...
```

The IDE's syntax highlighting may complain about not being allowed to inject, depending which you use, but my initial tests have this working

Comment: I'm trying to avoid annotation each and every test class, changing `@ContextConfiguration` to `@TestConfiguration` doesn't really help that (unless I can put `@TestConfiguration` on a superclass and avoid it on subclasses.) But didn't know this was possible, good to know :)

Comment: I don't have a class framework set up to confirm, but you may be able to put `@Inherited` onto the `@TestConfiguration`'s definition. Then put that on your base class - if that works, just say and I can update the answer.

Comment: FYI: `@RunWith` can _not_ be used as a meta-annotation. That's simply not supported by JUnit. Thus, I'm not sure what you are claiming works. With your example, the standard `JUnit4` runner would be used, not the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`.

Comment: I only carried out a very quick proof of concept test, which appeared to work, before I posted my solution. [Running on Spring 4.1.3, Junit 4.11]. I used a few autowired dependencies, and they were referenced and populated OK. However, examining the set up I had shows that I have an inherited @RunWith down my test suite hierarchy using the expected Spring class [I had only made minor modifications to a project I'm working on], so it gave a false positive.